# Linker command failed with exit code 1, unclear which compiler to use

Tags: gcc, makefile, clang

For a school assignment, I received a ZIP file containing a starting-point project. In it were a makefile, with a src file and stb_image file. Running `make` in the terminal leads to:

> ```
> base) kyleespinas@Kyles-MacBook-Air code_mac % make
> gcc -Wall -std=c99 -w -I./stb_image -c src/main.c -o src/main.o
> gcc -Wall -std=c99 -w -I./stb_image src/imageutil.o src/main.o src/helpers.o -o imageutil -lm 
> ld: Undefined symbols:
>   _resize_image_to_imatrix, referenced from:
>       _main in main.o
>   _transpose, referenced from:
>       _main in main.o
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make: *** [imageutil] Error 1
> ```

I have tried looking at my .json settings, switching my compilers, double checking import statements, and I am really lost. I haven't even been able to start doing the actual project since the starting code simply will not compile.  How can I fix this?

Comment: It's curious that `make`'s output shows only one source file being compiled, but three object files being included in the link.  Where are those other object files coming from, and why aren't they being compiled from source?  That could be a factor.

Comment: Have you considered that your compilation might be failing because you are expected to implement the missing functions yourself, and have not yet done so?  In any case, this is unlikely to be an issue of which compiler you should use, but we don't have enough information to tell you what the problem actually is.